# How to source workspace in python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros

I am using a python script in order to run four different python scripts that each execute a command, the purpose of this is to run the main python script on startup. This is what is inside the main python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
import os
os.system('x-terminal-emulator -e python ./one.py')
os.system('x-terminal-emulator -e python ./two.py')
os.system('x-terminal-emulator -e python ./three.py')
os.system('x-terminal-emulator -e python ./four.py')
```

When I run it, it does create four terminals and executes each of the .py in each terminal, but the one.py, two.py, and three.py return an error of "sh: 1: source: not found". I know this is because I am using these lines:

```
os.system('cd /home/nvidia/catkin_ws')
os.system('source devel/setup.bash')
```

Sourcing is needed in order the commands after it, how do I fix this problem? I am using ROS Kinetic with Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Content of one.py

```
#!/bin/bash
import os
os.system('cd /home/nvidia/catkin_ws')
os.system('source devel/setup.bash')
os.system('roslaunch pocketsphinx continuous.launch spdict:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/speaker_test.dic spkws:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/speaker_test.kwlist sphmm:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/speaker_verification/an4.ci_cont_adapt/ dict:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/keywords_spk_verification.dic kws:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/keywords_spk_verification.kwlist gram:=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/demo/asr_spk grammar:=asr rule:=rule sp_verif:=false')
```

Content of two.py

```
#!/bin/bash
import os
os.system('cd /home/nvidia/catkin_ws')
os.system('source devel/setup.bash')
os.system('rosrun pocketsphinx execute_commands.py')
```

Content of three.py

```
#!/bin/bash
import os
os.system('cd ~/catkin_astra')
os.system('source devel/setup.bash')
os.system('roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch')
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` as hashbang line for Python code is just wrong, even though it's irrelevant to your question. BTW: You should always extract a [mcve] from your code, because it helps you focus on the actual problem as well. In this case, `two.py` and `three.py` are completely irrelevant. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` starts a new shell, executes whatever you pass it and then closes the shell down again. Subsequently created shells are not affected by any changes to that shell, like changing the working directory or sourcing stuff.